# Images not showing in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've spent som time trying to fix it, but my app works fine except for the images that don't load into my recyclerview. I tried with and without firebase database to get the images but in both case i don't get them.
However i get all my texts so i don't understand where the problem comes from. I searched for quite a time and didn't see anything that i didn't do in other tutorials/helps.

In my logcat i get the following errors :

```
2021-05-27 20:31:25.445 22716-22716/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-05-27 20:31:25.447 22716-22716/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
```

And in the case of firebase Database i get the previous errors plus this one :

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I put here my code so you can check if you need

Activity class :

```
package fr.balizok.pizzaapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import fr.balizok.pizzaapplication.adapter.PizzaAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<PizzaModel> pizzaList = new ArrayList<PizzaModel>();
    RecyclerView recyclerViewPizzas;
    PizzaAdapter pizzaAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pizzaList.add(new PizzaModel(
                "Margherita",
                "Sauce tomate, Mozarella",
                "5.80€",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/08/16/49/pizza-5275191_960_720.jpg"));

        pizzaList.add(new PizzaModel(
                "Savoyarde",
                "Sauce tomate, Mozarella, Pomme de terre, Fromage",
                "10.20€",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/23/16/57/pizza-2973200_960_720.jpg"));

        pizzaList.add(new PizzaModel(
                "Poulet pesto",
                "Sauce tomate, Mozarella, Poulet, Pesto",
                "8.50€",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/08/00/03/pizza-1442945_960_720.jpg"));

        pizzaList.add(new PizzaModel(
                "4 Saisons",
                "Sauce tomate, Mozarella, Olive, Basilic, Jambon, Champignons, Artichaut",
                "9.60€",
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/08/00/03/pizza-1442946_960_720.jpg"));

        recyclerViewPizzas = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPizzas);
        recyclerViewPizzas.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewPizzas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        pizzaAdapter = new PizzaAdapter(MainActivity.this, pizzaList);
        recyclerViewPizzas.setAdapter(pizzaAdapter);
        recyclerViewPizzas.addItemDecoration(new PizzaItemDecoration());
    }
}
```

Adapter class :

```
package fr.balizok.pizzaapplication.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import fr.balizok.pizzaapplication.PizzaModel;
import fr.balizok.pizzaapplication.R;

public class PizzaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PizzaAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    List<PizzaModel> pizzaList;

    public PizzaAdapter(Context context, List<PizzaModel> pizzaList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pizzaList = pizzaList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_pizza_design,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PizzaAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PizzaModel currentPizza = pizzaList.get(position);

        holder.pizza_name.setText(currentPizza.getName());
        holder.ingredients.setText(currentPizza.getIngredients());
        holder.price.setText(currentPizza.getPrice());
        Glide.with(context).load(currentPizza.getImageURL()).into(holder.pizza_image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pizzaList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView pizza_image;
        TextView pizza_name, ingredients, price;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pizza_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizza_image);
            pizza_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pizza_name);
            ingredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me, thank you in advance !

Comment: try to run with debugging and set the breakpoint at `pizzaAdapter = new PizzaAdapter(MainActivity.this, pizzaList);` find URL is empty or URL hope helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow your code and make it demo its resolved by using Picasso library.
Try this one I hope it would be helpful to you.

```
 Picasso.get()
            .load(currentPizza.getImageURL())
            .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel) if you want
            .centerInside()
            .into(holder.pizza_image);
```

Comment: I don't know why but that worked for me too, thank you !